# Assets\Scripts\B1.cs(29,13): warning CS0618: 'LineRenderer.SetVertexCount(int)' is obsolete: 'Use positionCount instead.'

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm facing this issue on linerenderer:

```
LineRenderer lineRenderer = myObj.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
lineRenderer.SetVertexCount(2);
```

In the console it shows:

`warning CS0618: 'LineRenderer.SetVertexCount(int)' is obsolete: 'Use positionCount instead.'`

How do I resolve this warning?

Comment: Did you `Use positionCount instead.`? What happened?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The documentation on that topic : https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LineRenderer-positionCount.html

Answer (score 1):

Unity is saying that the function LineRenderer.SetVertexCount(int) is obsolete (aka you shouldn't use it) and you should use LineRenderer.positionCount instead.

Here is how you set it:
`LineRenderer lineRenderer = GetComponent<LineRenderer>(); lineRenderer.positionCount = value here;`

Replace 'value here' with a value or variable.